# WordPress - Query posts that do NOT have certain tag

Tags: wordpress

How can I specify in my posts query that I only want to have posts without any tags at all? Pretty simple question, don't think I need to elaborate much more than this.

So to get posts WITH a tag I would do `query_posts('tag=this')`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `tag__not_in(/* array of tag id values */)`.

If you wanted to exclude all tags, you would need to build up an array using the full list of tags retrieved using `get_tags()`. That method will return an array of tag objects, where the `term_id` property is the id for that tag. Example:

```
$tags = get_tags();
for ($i=0;  $i < count($tags); $i++)
{
    $tag_id_array[$i] = $tags[$i]->term_id;
}
```

For more info on query parameters, see [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Parameters).

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. When I add the `-` it gives me the post with the tags, not without. My code: `query_posts($query_string . '&order=asc&tag=-visiting');`

Comment: Sorry about that. I think that notation might only work with category id values. You should probably be using `tag__not_in(/* tag id values */)`. Let me know if that works, and I'll update this answer.